# How do I set up alerts on Facebook Marketplace?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications, facebook-marketplace

I have a handful of such alerts already setup and receive notifications about them from time to time but when I try to set up a new alert I can't seem to find how this is done.

How do I set up alerts on Facebook Marketplace?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the option to create new alerts has now been removed. Facebook is constantly making changes to the Marketplace portion of their app. Over time they add, remove, and change features.

https://thatbabylife.com/facebook-marketplace-alerts/

[image: Marketplace Alerts]

Comment: I have concluded the same thing, yet what I interpret the OP wants is that feature to be provided, somehow (well, ideally within Facebook itself), so I have posted to Software Recommendations a request for such: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/75156/online-tool-to-receive-email-notifications-matching-a-facebook-marketplace-searc

Answer (score 1):

As of this posting, it can be set up on the FB phone App. Go to the Marketplace. Search your term. Select the [image: alert icon]